# Migrate Aura components with lightning:actionOverride to LWC

Tags: aura, migration, lightning-web-components, lightning-action-override

In the LWC documentation I couldn't find anything on how to migrate Aura components using the `lightning:actionOverride` interface.

It is needed to override standard buttons on standard record pages.

Answer (score 8):

You can not do it as of now. The developer guide clearly mentions it.

**Migrate Interfaces**

> Implementing an Aura interface enables you to receive context data or
>   to surface your custom component in different contexts, such as in the
>   Lightning App Builder or Community Builder.

To receive context data in a Lightning web component, import the corresponding module. To surface a component in different contexts, use the targets metadata in your *.js-meta.xml configuration file.

> Aura interfaces that are not listed don’t currently have an equivalent
>   in Lightning Web Components.

```
these are the interfaces which lightning Web Component has an alternative:-     
      lightning:hasPageReference
     flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes
     flexipage:availableForRecordHome
     force:hasRecordId
     force:hasSObjectName
     forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes
     lightningcommunity:allowInRelaxedCSP
```

**Unsupported Experiences and Tools**

> Lightning Web Components doesn’t currently support these Salesforce
>   experiences and tools. To use a Lightning web component with these
>   experiences and tools, wrap the component in an Aura component.

```
Lightning Out
Lightning Components for Visualforce
Standalone Apps
Salesforce Console (Navigation Item API, Workspace API, UtilityBar API)
Utility Bars
URL Addressable Tabs
Flows
Snap-ins Chat
Lightning for Gmail, Outlook Integration
EMP API, Conversation Toolkit API, Omni Toolkit API, Quick Action API
Standard Action Overrides, Custom Actions, Global Actions, List View Actions, Related List View Actions
Chatter Extensions
```

Reference:- [Supported Salesforce Experiences and Tools](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_experiences) and [Migrate Interfaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/migrate_interfaces)

Comment: But how should I then migrate such components? Is there anything on the roadmap to allow this?

Comment: @RobertSösemann you can have parent aura component with needed interface and child web components. Aura components can include Lightning web components